# Having trouble with using ORM inside of route::resource

Tags: php, orm, laravel-5

I'm just following the book of Martin Bean to learn about Laravel 5. He start to teach about laravel with routers and after using some basic Route::get and Route::delete methods he gives a really short example of how to use Route::resource and he says that I let you to do this yourself :)

Structually there is no problem but I'm having trouble when I'm trying to pass ORM inside of the method.

Here is my CatsController.php

```
namespace firstApp\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use firstApp\Http\Requests;
use firstApp\Http\Controllers\Controller;
public function show(\firstApp\Cat $cat)
{
      return $cat;
      //return view('cats.show')->with('cat', $cat);
}
```

Here is how i use router

```
Route::resource('cats', 'CatsController');
```

And this is my Cat.php

```
-
namespace firstApp;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cat extends Model {
  public $timestamps = false;
  protected $fillable = ['name', 'date_of_birth', 'breed_id'];
  public function breed(){
    return $this->belongsTo('firstApp\Breed');
  }
}
```

When I call `http://localhost/firstApp/public/cats/2` an empty object is what I got..

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Asking for links to tutorials or other resources is off-topic on SO, so you should probably edit that part out (and your question stands without it).

Comment: @NathanTuggy Do you think I have to do it?

Comment: It's a close-vote bait right now, so no, you don't have to, but it will sure help keep your question open. Or hey, you can rely on the kindness of strangers a little more, they won't mind doing something you can just as easily do yourself, right?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'm sorry there could be misunderstanding because English is not my mother tongue.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You're injecting a model into the `show` method but not doing any queries to get the result.

To fix the problem, change your code to something like this:

```
public function show(\firstApp\Cat $cat, $id)
{
    return $cat->find($id);
}
```

Note that in the code above I also inject an `$id` into the `show` method, so when you hit the `http://localhost/firstApp/public/cats/2` URL, `2` will be stored in this variable.

In most cases people from Laravel community do the same thing as follows:

```
public function show($id)
{
    return \firstApp\Cat::find($id);
}
```

Good luck.